# Coloring shapes in winRT?

Tags: windows-runtime

My objective is to color a rectangle shape in winRT.When the brush leaves rectangle border the coloring should stop.So after coloring I need a fill colored rectangle.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Clip property to clip any element to a rectangle shape. Note though that right now it only support rectangle clips and for more you would need to use Direct2D or process all the pixels yourself.

Comment: Thanks.Clip property helps in case for rectangle.Could you please explain for other shpes how it can be done

Comment: You would need to learn about [XAML/DirectX interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh825871.aspx) and use layers with [geometric masks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756654(v=vs.85).aspx#geometricmasks). You can use SharpDX to do it with C# instead of using C++ directly, but most documentation is for using DirectX natively with C++. If you don't want to use Direct2D directly you could still do it with raster masks and WriteableBitmap, but that might be a bit slow. You could also use geometry, but that is a lot of algorithms to learn.